# php ajax search does not show results

Tags: php, ajax

I am working in a accounting system, then i want display the users when search by lastname or document, here is my

**search.php**

```
$busqueda = $_POST['busqueda'];
mysql_select_db($database_connectBD_fc, $connectBD_fc);

//busqueda por cedula
$query_registroClientes = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE num_documento LIKE '".$busqueda."' ORDER BY apellidos,nombres";
$registroClientes = mysql_query($query_registroClientes, $connectBD_fc) or die(mysql_error());
$row_registroClientes = mysql_fetch_assoc($registroClientes);

//busqueda por nombre
$query_busquedaClientes = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE apellidos LIKE '%".$busqueda."%' ORDER BY apellidos,nombres";
$busquedaClientes = mysql_query($query_busquedaClientes, $connectBD_fc) or die(mysql_error());
$row_busquedaClientes = mysql_fetch_assoc($busquedaClientes);

?>
<?php 
include 'dbc.php';
page_protect();
?>
<?php if($row_busquedaClientes==0){
          echo "<p class='text-success'>Búsqueda por apellido(s)</p>";?>
          <table class="tablas container-fluid">
          <tr class="tabla1 row">
            <td class="col-md-2">Apellidos</td>
            <td class="col-md-2 c-borde">Nombre</td>
            <td class="col-md-3">Correo Electronico</td>
            <td class="col-md-2 c-borde">Teléfono</td>
            <td class="col-md-1">Fecha ingreso</td>
            <td class="col-md-1 c-borde">Activo</td>
            <td class="col-md-1">Acciones</td>
          </tr>
          <?php do { ?>
            <tr class="info row">
              <td style="text-transform:Capitalize;"><strong><?php echo $row_busquedaClientes['apellidos']; ?></strong></td>
              <td class="c-borde" style="text-transform:Capitalize;"><?php echo $row_busquedaClientes['nombres']; ?></td>
              <td><?php if($row_busquedaClientes['correo'] == False){
                echo "<div class='label label-danger'><strong>No hay correo asignado.</strong></div>";
              }else{
                echo $row_busquedaClientes['correo'];
              } ?></td>
              <td class="c-borde"><?php echo $row_busquedaClientes['telefono']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_busquedaClientes['fecha_ingreso']; ?></td>
              <td class="c-borde">
                <?php
                  if($row_busquedaClientes['activo']=="1"){
                              echo "<span class='label label-success'>Si</div>";
                      }
                        else if($row_busquedaClientes['activo']=="0"){
                            echo "<span class='label label-danger'>No</div>";} ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php
                  if($row_busquedaClientes['idCliente']==""){echo " ";}
                          else{?>
                  <a href="clientesActualizar.php?num_cliente=<?php echo $row_busquedaClientes['idCliente']; ?>">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" title="Editar" style="color: #A5C63B; font-size: 20px;"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a href="clientesDetalles.php?num_cliente=<?php echo $row_busquedaClientes['idCliente']; ?>">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye" title="Ver detalles" style="color: #A5C63B; font-size: 20px;border:1px solid; border-width:0px 1px;padding:0 10px;"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a onclick="Borra('<? echo $row_busquedaClientes['idCliente']; ?>');" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" title="Eliminar" style="color: #dd2e3e; font-size: 20px;"></i>
                  </a>
                <?php } ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <?php } while ($row_busquedaClientes = mysql_fetch_assoc($busquedaClientes)); ?>
      </table> <?php } ?>
<?php
mysql_free_result($busquedaClientes);
?>
```

the idea is take the information the user and display in another page where i show all the users who are in the data base, here is where i show the search result

```
<div class="container botones-busqueda col-md-12">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-nuevo-cliente" href="clientesNew.php" role="button">Nuevo Cliente</a>
        <a class="btn btn-warning" href="vencimientos.php" role="button">Proximos a vencer</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="vencidos.php" role="button">Vencidos</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
      <form name="busqueda" id="busqueda" method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" name="busquedas" id="busquedas" style="color:black;" placeholder="Buscar, por apellidos">
            <input title="Buscar" class="fa fa-search" id="buscar" type="submit" value="Buscar">
          <label for="cedula"></label>
      </form>
      <?php
        if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
      echo "<div class=\"error\">$_GET[msg]</div>";
      }
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<section class="container">
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</section>
```

is where i display all the users, using the code `<?php do{} while ($row_registroClientes = mysql_fetch_assoc($registroClientes)); ?>` inside display all the users, well i hope someone can help me.

here is my **ajax** code

```
<script language="JavaScript">
      function Borra(idcontacto)
      {
      var agree=confirm("¿Realmente desea eliminar el contacto seleccionado?");
      if (agree) { document.location="clientesDel.php?num_cliente="+idcontacto; }
      else return false ;
      }
      $(function(){
      $('#busquedas').focus();
      $('#busqueda').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      })
      $('#busquedas').keyup(function(){
        var envio = $('#buscar').val();
        $('#resultado').html('<p class="text-success">Buscando al cliente.</p>');
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'busqueda.php',
          data: ('busqueda='+envio),
          success: function(resp){
            if (resp!="") {
              $('#resultado').html(resp);
            }
          }
        })
      })
    })
    </script>
```

Thanks you.